# Warning when adding new aduser to group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As part of my create user script I'm adding users to two AD Security groups based on their company. The user is being added to the group but I receive a warning. I'm confused on why I would receive the warning when the user is still being added correctly.

WARNING: Could not add member(s) to ADGroup: 'CN=HS,CN=Users,DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN'. Error is: 'The specified account name is already a member of the group'.

WARNING: Could not add member(s) to ADGroup: 'CN=HS Students,CN=Users,DC=My,DC=DOMAIN'. Error is: 'The specified account name is already a member of the group'.

Here is my create user script

```
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
#Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a  variable as below

$Username   = $User.ID
$Password   = $User.BDATE
$Firstname  = $User.FNAME
$Lastname   = $User.LNAME
$Department = $User.GRD
$Company    = $User.SCHID #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be moved to

# Choose OU
Switch ($Company)
{
    "1480" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=hs,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
    "1479" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=elem,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
}

#Check to see if the user already exists in AD
if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
{
     #If user does exist, give a warning
     Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
}
else
{
    #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
    "Processing started (on " + $date + "): " | Out-File $log -append
    "--------------------------------------------" | Out-File $log -append

    #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
    New-ADUser `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -UserPrincipalName "$Username@clasd.net" `
        -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
        -GivenName $Firstname `
        -Department "$Department" `
        -Company "$Company" `
        -EmailAddress "$Username@clasd.net" `
        -Surname $Lastname `
        -Enabled $True `
        -Scriptpath "login.vbs" `
        -DisplayName "$Firstname $Lastname" `
        -Path $OU `
        -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
        -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

    #Start-Sleep 5

    # Add User to Groups
    Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1480"' | %{Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf "HS", "HS Students"}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user isn't "being added correctly" as you say.

The warning is just telling you that your command has not completed its function because the action it is trying to perform has already been done.

**EDIT**: You can set the WarningAction Parameter to SilentlyContinue to suppress the yellow warning text if you don't want it to appear:

```
Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1480"' | %{Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf "HS", "HS Students" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1479"' | %{Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf "Elem", "Elem Students" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
```

These two commands also need to be moved to the end of your script - so they are outside the foreach loop. This means they only run once after all the new accounts have been created.

Comment: I want to add every user where company is 1480 to hs and hs students and every user that company is 1479 to elem and elem students

Answer (score 1):

so, why are you doing get-aduser, you are getting all the users that have the company set to 1480? you would need to do something like:

```
New-ADUser @args -PassThru | 
  ForEach-Object { Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf "HS", "HS Students" }
```

ALso yeah, consider creating a hashtable with all the values you needs and splatting it to a new-aduser command, looks much clearner, like so:

```
$args = @{
    DisplayName = $_.DisplayName 
    GivenName = $_.GivenName
    Surname = $_.sn
    SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
    UserPrincipalName = $($_.SamAccountName + "@xxx.xxx")
    Department = $_.Department
    Title = $_.Title
    City = $_.City
    Office = $_.Office
    MobilePhone = $_.MobilePhone
    OfficePhone = $_.telephoneNumber
    Name = $_.DisplayName
    Company = "xxx"
    Path = $path
    State = $region
}
New-ADUser @args -PassThru
```

Comment: yea using a hashtable is nice. But my way works too doesn't it? Or is the best practice way to use hashtables?

Comment: no, it doesn't matter, your way works fine, its just the hashtable way is easier to look at.